# How do I get the correct NER using SpaCy from text like "F.B.I. Agent Peter Strzok, Who Criticized Trump in Texts, Is Fired"?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

How do I get the correct NER using SpaCy from text like "F.B.I. Agent Peter Strzok, Who Criticized Trump in Texts, Is Fired - The New York Times SectionsSEARCHSkip to contentSkip to site." 
here "Criticized Trump" is recognized as person instead of "Trump" as person.

How to pre-process and lower case the text like "Criticized" or "Texts" from the above string to overcome above issue or any other technique to do so.

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from collections import Counter
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
from pprint import pprint

sent = ("F.B.I. Agent Peter Strzok, Who Criticized Trump in Texts, Is Fired - The New York Times SectionsSEARCHSkip to contentSkip to site")
doc = nlp(sent)
pprint([(X, X.ent_iob_, X.ent_type_) for X in doc])
```

Result from above code:-
"Criticized Trump" as 'PERSON' and "Texts" as 'GPE'

Expected result should be:-
"Trump" as 'PERSON' instead of "Criticized Trump" as 'PERSON'  and "Texts" as '' instead of "Texts" as 'GPE'

Comment: Did the pre-processing using POS tagging work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more examples of Named Entities to tune the NER model. Here you have all the information needed for the preparation of train data https://spacy.io/usage/training. You can use prodigy (annotation tool from spaCy creators, https://prodi.gy) to mark Named Entities in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you can pre-process using POS tagging in order to change to lower case words like "Criticized" or "Texts" which are not proper nouns.
Proper capitalization (lower vs. upper case) will help the NER tagger.

```
sent = "F.B.I. Agent Peter Strzok, Who Criticized Trump in Texts, Is Fired - The New York Times SectionsSEARCHSkip to contentSkip to site"
doc = nlp(sent)

words = []
spaces = []
for a in doc:

    if a.pos_ != 'PROPN':
        words.append( a.text.lower() )
    else:
        words.append(a.text)

    spaces.append(a.whitespace_)

spaces = [len(sp) for sp in spaces]    
docNew = Doc(nlp.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)
print(docNew)
# F.B.I. Agent Peter Strzok, who criticized Trump in texts, is fired - the New York Times SectionsSEARCHSkip to contentskip to site
```